# How can I start a thread from another and restart a thread after execution?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 threads, the "main" thread which starts a secondary thread to run a little process.

The "main" thread must wait for the secondary thread for a few of seconds to complete the process, after that time, the "main" thread must start again no matter what happened with the process of the secondary thread.

If the secondary process ended earlier, the "main" thread must start to work again.

How can I start a thread from another, wait for the end of execution, and restart the thread after?

I have a code here, but the ExampleRun class, must wait, for example, 10 sec and start again, no matter what happend with MyProcess

```
public class ExampleRun {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    MyProcess t = new MyProcess();
    t.start();

    synchronized (t) {
        try {
            t.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
public class MyProcess extends Thread {

public void run() {
    System.out.println("start");

    synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            try {
                System.out.println("I sleep");
                sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        flag = true;
        System.out.println("Wake up");
        notify();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is to use `Thread.join(timeout)`.

Also, **do not** use `synchronized`, `wait`, or `notify` on `Thread` objects. This will interfere with the `Thread.join` implementation. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join-long-) for details.

Here's what your main program would look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyProcess t = new MyProcess();
    t.start();

    try {
        t.join(10000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        System.out.println("interrupted");
    }

    System.out.println("Main thread resumes");
}
```

Note that when the main thread resumes after the `join()` call, it can't tell whether the child thread completed or whether the call timed out. To test this, call `t.isAlive()`.

Your child thread of course could do anything, but it's important for it not to use `synchronized`, `wait`, or `notify` on itself. For example, here's a rewrite that avoids using these calls:

```
class MyProcess extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyProcess starts");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {
                System.out.println("MyProcess sleeps");
                sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("MyProcess finishes");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple lock method:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // create new lock object
    Object lock = new Object();
    // create and start thread
    Thread t = new Thread(() ->
    {
        // try to sleep 1 sec
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { /* do something */ }
        // notify main thread
        synchronized (lock) { lock.notifyAll(); }
    };
    t.start();
    // wait for second thread to finish
    synchronized (lock)
    {
        while (t.isAlive())
            lock.wait();
    }
    // second thread finished
    System.out.println("second thread finished :)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call [`Thread.join()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) on the `Thread` you want to wait for, per the Javadoc,

> Waits for this thread to die.

Alternatively, you could use a [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and simply call [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29), from its' Javadoc,

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.